# How to specify ffmpeg profile for h264_omx encoder?

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi3, h.264, video-encoding, hardware-acceleration

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3B with ffmpeg version 3.2.10-1~deb9u1+rpt1.

I need to encode a h.264 file using the Baseline profile, but I can't find a way to specify this on the ffmpeg command line.  Using -profile:v baseline yields the following error:

```
[h264_omx @ 0x185b0e0] [Eval @ 0x7e8c82e0] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'baseline'
[h264_omx @ 0x185b0e0] Unable to parse option value "baseline"
[h264_omx @ 0x185b0e0] Error setting option profile to value baseline.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (h264_mmal) -> h264 (h264_omx))
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

This option works with libx264 (software encoder), but in this application the hardware-accelerated encoder (OMX) must be used.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: An answered on the ML, you'll need ver 3.3 or later.

Comment: OK thanks. I am compiling newest  from source. Are you aware of a precompiled repo for raspberry pi?